# How to efficiently add random numbers to an array until a cumulative sum is reached?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What is an efficient way to add random numbers to an array until the cumluative sum of the array reaches a threshold value?

My specific case is that I would like to simulate a homogenous poisson process with a given rate for a given time period. To calculate the timings of 'events', I am sampling from the exponential distrobution, I need to keep sampling untill the cumulative sum of the events reaches a threshold value.

Thanks!

```py
def homogenous_poisson_process(rate, t_stop, t_start=0):
    """ Return timings of events arrising from a homogenous poisson process of a
    given rate (intensity) between a given start and stop times
    """
    beta = 1 / rate
    events = []
    last_event = 0
    while True:
        new_event = np.random.exponential(scale=beta)
        new_event += last_event
        if new_event > (t_stop - t_start):
            break
        else:
            events.append(new_event)
            last_event = new_event
    return np.array(events) + t_start
```

Comment: Seems fairly efficient to me. How much faster do you need it?

Comment: I have no specific speed requirements nor am I trained in testing software speed. Calling a funtion and going through if else statements potentially millions of time inside a for loop "seemed" like it would be inefficient to me. Is this not the case?

Comment: You could draw a single count n from the appropriate Poisson distribution for your desired interval and intensity and then draw n uniforms and sort them.

Comment: Paul Panzer this is a really cool idea. Thanks!